# How to set a fixed IP address for the Gnome Boxes virtual machine

Tags: gnome, ssh, virtualization, ip

I run an instance of Ubuntu on my computer using the Gnome Boxes VM, and I use ssh to interact with it. However, every time I restart my host pc, the IP address associated with the Ubuntu instance changes, requiring me to update aliases and my ssh config, which is very annoying.

Does anyone know how to change the behavior so the server instance never changes its IP address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been fixed in GNOME Boxes 3.30, see https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-boxes/commit/8a336ba05

You should upgrade to a newest Ubuntu or try the GNOME Boxes 3.32 Flatpak from https://flathub.org/apps/details/org.gnome.Boxes